# How to get a MPMediaItem from MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

How can i get MPMediaItem from MPMoviePlayerController as i can get it in case of MusicPlayer as follows

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
```

But how to get it from MPMoviePlayerController? Is it even possible?

Infact i want to get the information about the current movie item playing, for example its title, artist etc, is it possible to get the metadata for a video file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you finaly find out a solution, but I do this way and it works great :

```
MPMediaItem *nowPlayingMediaItem = [myPlayer nowPlayingItem];
```

You can only call accessors and mutators using the "dot-syntaxe". For other methods you must use Obejctive-C "message-style-syntaxe".